# HP Proliant cannot find Seagate SATA HDD

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, sata

1785-Slot X Drive Array Not Configured (HP Proliant ML10 v2 cannot recognize Seagate 1Gb SATA HDD)

I have a HP Proliant ML10 v2 and a Seagate 1TB SATA HDD. My computer cannot recognize the HDD so I cannot install Window now. Every time I boot it up, after POST, the message is:

1785-Slot X Drive Array Not Configured 
Run Array Configuration Utility

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the [HP Smart Storage Administrator utility](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5409020) to create a logical drive on your physical hard disk.

Otherwise, you won't be able to see the disks in your operating system.

Please read [HP's detailed instructions](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0128448) on how to configure the RAID on an HP ProLiant ML10v2 server.

Comment: How do I install it?

Comment: My computer does not have a optical drive. I can boot from USB tho. Right now I have one USB for installing Windows. Can I install HP Smart Storage Administrator utility from an USB

Comment: Press `F8` or `F10` when prompted during the server boot.

Comment: F10 does not lead to anything.

Comment: F9 goes to ROM based utility set up. F8 is for iLO but after the POST

Comment: @mle95 Read the [instructions from HP](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0128448).

Comment: It said mount the ISO image using iLO virtual media or burn the ISO in a bootable DVD. So can I use a my USB to do that (create a bootable USB using the HP Smart Storage Administrator ISO then install the program)

Comment: If you would like to, sure.

Comment: In Step 7, it said boot using OS disk. I will replace it with a USB rght? In Step 8, it said when prompted for controller driver, provide the drivers which were kept ready as per step 6, via USB Key of iLO Virtual Folder. How do I use USB key of iLO virtual Folder. Does this mean I install Window and when I choose the drive I pick Load Driver and insert a USB with the controller driver?