# Install new G Skill Ripsaw X RAM into HP Proliant ML10 v2 causes black screen and long beep

Tags: memory, hp-proliant

So I have a HP Proliant ML10 v2 and 3x4Gb G Skill Ripsaw X DDR3-1600 PC3-12800 1.5V. The computer does not show POST and then proceeds to a long beep. I removed the new RAM and boot and then everything is OK again.

Here is the RAM: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231428. I'm sure that it is unbuffed DIMM.

I think it might be a problem with:
1. Defective RAM (unlikely but might happen)
2. BIOS

Comment: The RAM is fine, it's just not compatible with servers which require ECC RAM.

Answer (score 5):

I went to HP's website and looked up the specs for this HP machine and look what I found:

[image: HP RAM]

(It's reiterated again a couple lines down. "Non-ECC DIMMs are not supported.")

Then I clicked on that Newegg link that you posted, and I looked at the specs of that RAM you have.  And it says:

> ECC:         No

Comment: Ok guess I will return the RAM. Any recommendation for a RAM to buy?

Comment: @mle95 Yes. Use HP ram and [HP disks](http://serverfault.com/questions/764707/hp-proliant-cannot-find-seagate-sata-hdd).